# Is there a way to run logic ONLY IF there is at least one user subscribed to a websocket topic?

Tags: spring, websocket

I have a working Spring websocket/STOMP application that receives a bunch of remote data. I then want to refine that data further for specific tables/charts in the users' browsers, but I don't want to run that logic if there are no users connected.

Here's some pseudocode (Kotlin) of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Component
class SendAccessLogMetrics(private val simpMessageSendingOperations: SimpMessageSendingOperations,
                           private val accessLogStats: AccessLogStats) {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    fun sendAccessLogMetrics() {
        if ( ... people are subscribed to /message/test ... ) {
            val chartData = createChartData(accessLogStats)
            simpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSend("/message/test", chartData)
        }
    }

}
```

##### Aside:

I feel like this is a really common need, and I'm just missing something or searching on the wrong terms. Any advice regarding this setup is appreciated.

I think I can use events to manage the subscribed counts manually, but considering Spring has a list of connected/subscribed clients to send messages to, I shouldn't have to, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for online users and their subscriptions in the `DefaultSimpUserRegistry` if you plan to run your spring application in a single server only.

In a clustered scenario (with an external broker) you have to use `MultiServerUserRegistry` and configure a topic in `StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setUserRegistryBroadcast` that replicas use to share the content of their local user registry.